# Oracle Apex - Optional List of Values (LOV)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov

Is there a way in Oracle APEX to use a list of values or select list but do not force the user to select an item and allow them to enter different items?

The basic functionality which I require is similar to a combo box where you can optionally select an item from the list or enter a completely new.

Thanks Mark

Comment: I did not realise it was that simple.  The first time I used in the list of values the text box was disabled.

Comment: The text box being disabled is not related to it having a list of values - some item types have disabled text boxes, others don't. I've found it instructive to create items with all the various item types, so I can try them out - that way when I have a particular requirement, I already know which item types may be suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

1. you could use a Popup LOV item type, where the user can type anything they want, and the LOV is only used to give them suggestions if they click the LOV button.
2. you could use a Select List, and set Display Null = Yes; but then the user cannot enter their own values.

Comment: just make sure you dont try an validate against the LOV tho..  the 'new' values will fail.

Comment: @ShoeLace, good point. (I will sometimes base my LOV off a distinct query from the column that the item is for, if it's a smallish table - that way new values automatically appear in the LOV.)

Comment: yes i always base LOV's of table queries.. and poplists for small fixed (non db) values

Comment: Hi Jeff... [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4129656) doesnt work for changing LOV button text... Do you know how I can change it ?

Comment: @JasonKrs, this is not a chat forum. If you have another question, ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use a Popup LOV and UNION it with the values already entered into the target table. It would be slower and ordering would be more constrained.
2. For large tables you could have a process that compared the distinct set of values in the target table with those in the lookup table and entered new ones into the lookups table.